# $f$ is absolutely continuous implies that $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing, absolute-continuity

I am going to show that if f is absolutely continuous it implies that f is continuous, the test seems somewhat trivial to me of the definition, however I would like to know if I am doing it well.

If $f$ is absolutely continuos on [a,b], let $\varepsilon >0$, there exist $\delta>0$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}|f(b_{k})-f(a_{k})|<\varepsilon$, if $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(b_{k}-a_{k})<\delta$, for some collection finite $\lbrace (a_{k},b_{k}),1\leq k \leq n\rbrace$.

If $n=1$, $|b_{1}-a_{1}|<\delta$ implies $|f(b_{1})-f(a_{1})|<\varepsilon$, then $f$ is uniformly continous on $[a,b]$

Comment: Do you want uniform continuity or just continuity?

Comment: Your proof is correct: considering one segment $[a_1,b_1]$ in the definition of the absolute continuity immediately shows uniform continuity (and thereby continuity of course).

Comment: @ArcticChar, I show that $f$ is uniform continuous , hence  $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let  $ c\in [a,b]$  and $\epsilon>0$.

$f $ is absolutely continuous at $ [a,b]$ $$\implies$$

$$\exists \delta>0\;\; : \; \forall (a_1,b_1)\in [a,b]^2\;$$
$$ |a_1-b_1|<\delta \implies |f(a_1)-f(b_1)|<\epsilon$$

$$\implies$$
$$\exists \delta>0\;\; :\;\; \forall x\in[a,b]$$
$$|x-c|<\delta \;\;\implies \;\;|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$$
This proves that $ f$ is continuous at any point $ c\in [a,b].$